# Failed to load xml document {ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog}. Incorrect function

Tags: c#, логирование

Использую ETW Logging чтобы записат лог в Windows Event Viewer. Установил пакет Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource с nuget. Папка Debug

[image: Debug]
Испольняю каманду через командную строку

```
wevtutil.exe im {"ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog"} /rf:"{ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog.etwManifest.dll}" /mf:"{ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog.etwManifest.dll}"
```

После чего выдаёт ошибку

```
Failed to load xml document {ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog}. Incorrect function.
```

Кто нибудь использует ETW чтобы записат лог в Windows Event Viewer. Помогите исправит команду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно присвоит полный путь манифеста и dll- ку:

```
wevtutil.exe im "C:\repos\ETW loggiing\ETW loggiing\bin\Debug\ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog.etwManifest.man" /rf:"C:\repos\ETW loggiing\ETW loggiing\bin\Debug\ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog.etwManifest.dll" /mf:"C:\repos\ETW loggiing\ETW loggiing\bin\Debug\ETW loggiing.Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog.etwManifest.dll"
```